# DHCP, AD all stops every day

Tags: active-directory, dhcp

I have a serious issue with our Active Directory network. I'll try and keep this brief and to the point.

Problem:-  DHCP, AD all stop working every day.

Background:- 1 single server 2012 R2, running DNS, DHCP and AD, running on VMWARE 6 Hypervisor.  Problem resolved with a reboot of the VM - all domain functions and DHCP function fine after reboot.  Running DCDIAG, metadata cleanup, several 3rd party active directory tools to look for errors - all pass fine with no issues reported.

No Antivirus running. Nothing has changed. Seems to have been occurring since around 24th of May.

Symptoms - DHCP stops issuing IPs, then all entries show a RED cross.
  Restarting DHCP results in `Error 14:- Not enough storage available to process this operation.`

Users can't login remotely using VPN

I can't load Active Directory Users and Computers.

Errors:- DHCP >

> The DHCP server cannot be located. The DHCP server might be down,
>   there might be network problems or the DHCP service might not be
>   installed.

The error was:  The DHCP server service is not running on the target computer.

AD >> Active Directory Domain Services.

> Data from Domain Controllers is not available from Domain Controller
>   xyz.company.local because: The Server is not operational. Try again
>   later or choose another DC by selecting Connect to Domain.

I'm totally at a loss as to what is wrong here.  Please can someone help?

Comment: Have you checked free storage on %SystemDrive%?

Comment: This often seems to be an issue with system resources other than disk space. See for example https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/abizerh/2009/07/12/troubleshooting-the-error-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operation/

Comment: Is the timing of failure predictable? Can you gather stats on system resources (such as handles - see link above) to see if they're heading for exhaustion?

Comment: I will take a look at all comments now and will report back.  Thank you.

Comment: @PaterSiul - if you mean physical disk space on C drive, there is over 300GB free.  Also VMWARE Datastore has over 500GB of free space.

Comment: @PaulHaldane I've looked at your link - thank you.  Doesn't appear to have the same options for the task manager using 2012.  So I downloaded the handle fro sysinternals and outputted to a file.  Not too sure what I am looking for within the handle output?  Could I post here?

Comment: I've managed to <add> HANDLES to task manager (not sure if this is the correct thing to do) the order is as follows;  DNS = 5406, LSASS= 3739,  svchost.exe = 3163, explorer.exe 2089, microsoft activedirectory - 1640 and so on (in order)

Comment: 2 things I have noticed though.......... Lanmanserver registry key seemed short of 5 keys compared to other 2012 servers I have access too.  All the others have the same amount of DWORD 32bit values whereas this single domain 2012 server doensn't.  Registry backed up and added a few keys. Also noticed on 26th May when this occurred,  Synology Assistant was installed.  I have removed this - server rebooted time will tell over the next 24 hours.

Comment: @PaulHaldane  No luck:-(  It is still failing with same errors.  The only reboot resolves the issue.  Please, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

following an update and it is entirely possible that my DHCP service is not properly authorized. Possibly in relation to this my DHCP server is stopping to due to rouge DHCP server detection. Which I'm working on and may be a virus on a PC (already isolated the offending PC). The lazy way to deal with it would be to create this registry key on your "authorized" DHCP server.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dhcpserver\Parameters\

create a DWORD called "DisableRogueDetection" and assign a value of 1.